# Will I have to turn my array into a 3d array?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am creating a program which has the following desired output:

[image]

I am trying to see if I am on the right track. My goal is to write all three number inputs into an array, then into the .dat file.

Would I need to create a 3d matrix like so: `numbers[3][5]`?

If I do this I run into the issue where I'm having a lot of difficulty storing, writing, and printing the array properly to look like the result below. It is okay though, I can research that myself if so. I am just looking for a tiny bit of direction.

My Current working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// function prototypes
void writeToDat(int numbers[5]);
void writeToArray(int number, int numbers[5]);
void displayArray(int numbers[5]);
int getNumber(int number);

// begin main function
int main(void){

    int number;
    int numbers[5]={0,0,0,0,0};

    number = getNumber(number);
    writeToArray(number, numbers);
    displayArray(numbers);
    writeToDat(numbers);

    return 0;

} // end main function

void displayArray(int numbers[5]){

    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    }

} // end displayArray function

// function which gets the array ready to go
void writeToArray(int number, int numbers[5]){

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int count=1;

    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        numbers[j] = (number*count) ;
        count++;

    }

} // end function writeToArray

int getNumber(int number){

    number = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number (0 to terminate): ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    return number;
} // end function getNumber

// function which writes the current array into the .dat file
void writeToDat(int numbers[5]){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("question4.dat","w");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("question3.dat cannot be opened!\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the fil!\n");
    } 

    else{

    int j=0;

        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            fprintf(file, "%d ,", numbers[j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

} // end function writeToDat
```

Here is my attempty for the 3D array before I asked for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// function prototypes
void writeToDat(int numbers[3][5]);
void writeToArray(int number, int numbers[3][5], int *arrayCount);
void displayArray(int numbers[3][5]);
int getNumber(int number, int *arrayCount);

// begin main function
int main(void){

    int number;
    int numbers[3][5];
    int * arrayCount=0;

    number = getNumber(number, arrayCount);

    writeToArray(number, numbers, arrayCount);
    arrayCount++;

    number = getNumber(number, arrayCount);

    writeToArray(number, numbers, arrayCount);
    arrayCount++;

    displayArray(numbers);
    writeToDat(numbers);

    return 0;

} // end main function

void displayArray(int numbers[3][5]){

    int i=0;
    int j=0;


    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++){

        printf("%d ", numbers[i][j]);
            }printf("\n");
    }

} // end displayArray function

// function which gets the array ready to go
void writeToArray(int number, int numbers[3][5], int *arrayCount){

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int count=1;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
        numbers[i][j] = (number*count)  ; 
        count++;
    }
    }
} // end function writeToArray

int getNumber(int number, int *arrayCount){


    number = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number (0 to terminate): ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    return number;
} // end function getNumber

// function which writes the current array into the .dat file
void writeToDat(int numbers[3][5]){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("question4.dat","w");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("question3.dat cannot be opened!\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the fil!\n");
    } 

    else{

    int j=0;
    int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){

        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            fprintf(file, "%d ,", numbers[i][j]);
        }
            }
    }
    fclose(file);

} // end function writeToDat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a lot of extra work for a simple task. Why not append the numbers to the text file as you receive input? This cuts out the middle man and a lot of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("question4.dat","w");
    int n, i;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter a number (0 to terminate): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n == 0) {
            break;
        }

        for (i = n; i <= 5 * n; i += n) {
            fprintf(file, "%d ", i);
        }

        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Please enter a number (0 to terminate): 3
Please enter a number (0 to terminate): 5
Please enter a number (0 to terminate): 2
Please enter a number (0 to terminate): 0
$ cat *.dat
3 6 9 12 15
5 10 15 20 25
2 4 6 8 10
```

Worth noting is that `numbers[3][5]` is a 2d array rather than a 3d array (that'd be `numbers[][][]`).

If you're still set on choosing the array approach, consider a redesign. Your proposed 2d program is based entirely around a [hard-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) array size of 3. You'll need to potentially overwrite these arrays to fulfill the promise your UI is making ("0 to terminate"). Consider [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) if you need to maintain all input in memory.